# Error downloading files with DownloadFile in powershell 2

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have the need to download files under powershell 2.

Since Invoke-WebRequest is not supported in version 2, I try to use DownloadFile but I always get the same error and I don't know how to fix it.

```
 PS C:\Users\user> [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

:: : Exception setting "SecurityProtocol": "Cannot convert null to type "System.Net.SecurityProtocolType" due to invali
d enumeration values. Specify one of the following enumeration values and try again. The possible enumeration values ar
e "Ssl3, Tls"."
At line:1 char:28
+ [Net.ServicePointManager]:: <<<< SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

PS C:\Users\user> $client = new-object System.Net.WebClient

PS C:\Users\user> $client.DownloadFile("https://web.com/test.txt", "C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.txt")
DownloadFile : Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpec
ted error occurred on a send."
At line:1 char:21
+ $client.DownloadFile <<<< ("https://web.com/test.txt", "C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.txt")
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

What I can do?

Comment: Have you tried with `http://` URL?

Comment: I can't because the repository is HTTPS.

Comment: As aside: Why are you still using PowerShell 2.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting an error setting the TLS version, you may want to check which protocols are available:

```
[Net.SecurityProtocolType]::GetValues( 'Net.SecurityProtocolType' )
```

However, I don't know how the protocol availability will be affected by using such an old version.  Moreover, I don't know how specific protocol settings on a given system affect the availability of protocols either at large or as returned by the above command.

In fact, I would point out the error itself only reflects SSL3 & Tls. On my system when I enter an invalid enumerator the error reports `Ssl3,Tls,Tls11,Tls12,Tls13` as choices.  While my system is configured to disable everything below Tls12 and has no settings defined for Tls13.

The best assumption I can make is .Net 2.0 which is used with PowerShell 2.0 cannot use Tls12 as it's not present in the enumerators and based on comparison with my system the enums aren't affected by explicit enabling/disabling of protocols.

In any case, I think you have to clear up the first error before you worry about the second.  The second error may well be due to the TLS incompatibility.  The easiest way to do this would be to upgrade PowerShell (along with the required .Net version).  PowerShell 2.0 can coexist with Windows PowerShell 5.1 though you may have to launch with the `-Version 2.0` parameter.  Also, make sure the engine is installed as a Windows feature. DISCLAIMER: verify all that on your own.

I know the Windows PowerShell 2.0 Engine (PowerShell-V2) was available as a feature at least as late as Windows 2012 R2.

I would also point out that PowerShell 7.x (aka PowerShell Core) can be installed side by side with Windows PowerShell. Potentially this could sidestep the aforementioned complications, allowing you to do run the task at hand...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my machine does not have support for TLS12 under powershell 2.0.

Comment: Why don't you try and run the script from a machine that does have TLS1.2. If it works it'll double confirm our suspicion that the website is not allowing a lower version.  Can you try and install a higher version PowerShell & .Net? What's holding you to PoSh 2.0?   I actually had the same issue for a long time because Exchange 2010 couldn't use newer versions, but I was able to run 5.1 concurrently.  and PowerShell Core is designed to coexist with Windows PowerShell.  These options could definitely get you past this.